# How to transform a array object in new object?

Tags: javascript

I have the following array object:

```
  var data = [
    {id:'value.id_1', name: 'value.name_1', type: 'value.type_1', value: 'value.value_1'},
    {id:'value.id_2', name: 'value.name_2', type: 'value.type_2', value: 'value.value_2'},
    {id:'value.id_3', name: 'value.name_3', type: 'value.type_3', value: 'value.value_3'},
  ]
```

and I would like to create a new array object like this :

```
 var request = [
     {
       "value.id_1" : "value.value_1",
       "value.id_2" : "value.value_2",
       "value.id_3" : "value.value_3",
     }
 ]
```

how to proceed to do it ?

Cordially

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map

Comment: An object can't have same key value

Comment: @zooly I modified the statement

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Iterate your data array, and assign `id` `value` in new object.

*Note* : Object keys can't be the same.

```js
  var data = [
    {id:'value.id', name: 'value.name', type: 'value.type', value: 'value.value'},
    {id:'value.id2', name: 'value.name2', type: 'value.type2', value: 'value.value2'},
    {id:'value.id3', name: 'value.name3', type: 'value.type3', value: 'value.value3'},
  ]
  
  var result = {}
  
  data.forEach(d => {
   result[d.id] = d.value
  })
  
  console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try this

```js
  var data = [
    {id:'value.id_1', name: 'value.name_1', type: 'value.type_1', value: 'value.value_1'},
    {id:'value.id_2', name: 'value.name_2', type: 'value.type_2', value: 'value.value_2'},
    {id:'value.id_3', name: 'value.name_3', type: 'value.type_3', value: 'value.value_3'},
  ]
let request = data.map(function(item){
    let newItem = {};
      newItem[item.id] = item.value;
    return newItem;  
    })
    console.log(request);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use of `Array.reduce` to create a new object based on the array of object you initially have.

What we do inside of the reduce is to assign new key/value into an object that we returns.

```js
 var data = [
    {id:'value.id', name: 'value.name', type: 'value.type', value: 'value.value'},
    {id:'value.id2', name: 'value.name', type: 'value.type', value: 'value.value'},
    {id:'value.id3', name: 'value.name', type: 'value.type', value: 'value.value'},
  ];

const ret = data.reduce((tmp, {
 id,
 value,
}) => (tmp[id] = value, tmp), {});

console.log(ret);
```

---

Equivalent to :

```js
var data = [
    {id:'value.id', name: 'value.name', type: 'value.type', value: 'value.value'},
    {id:'value.id2', name: 'value.name', type: 'value.type', value: 'value.value'},
    {id:'value.id3', name: 'value.name', type: 'value.type', value: 'value.value'},
  ];

const ret = data.reduce((tmp, x) => (tmp[x.id] = x.value, tmp), {});

console.log(ret);
```